# Approaches to provide a Qt Gui via Web?

Tags: qt, web-services, user-interface, qt5

Sometimes I stumble upon frameworks that used to provide a web interface for Qt applications (like e.g. https://github.com/alberthier/qtwui)

Is there today a Qt5 way (or even better PyQt5) to run a Qt application on a server while accessing the UI via web?

Comment: I propose not to close this question as offtopic, because topic is interested for Qt community.

Answer (score 2):

I know several conceptions, but from my point of view they are not ready for production.

1. Emscripten: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/09/25/qt-for-native-client-and-emscripten
2. QML Web: https://github.com/qmlweb/qmlweb

Answer (score 2):

[WebGL streaming](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/02/22/qt-quick-webgl-streaming/) is one way forward, as it allows to run both QML and widget-based UIs in the browser.

Comment: Really awesome. Thanks for that hit,